# Text got all messed up (misaligned) in an article

Tags: css, joomla-3.5

I had a similar issue before in the footer, but it was solved when I used this code:

```
.bottom-d-outer p {
margin: 0 0 9px;
}
```

Now I've noticed that I have the same issue in an article and I'm not sure how to solve it there too...
It's here:

https://kotkovski.com/ru/statya-na-russkom-ne-featured

You can see it in an article just below the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but your template has the following code:

```
p, hr, dl, blockquote, pre, fieldset, figure {
    margin: -15px 0;
}
```

In this file:

> https://kotkovski.com/templates/jp-x2/warp/css/base.css

As you can see, it's setting a negative margin, therefore pushing each paragraph up.

In your template's **custom.css** file near the top, add the following code to reset the margin:

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: The reason for that code was to move Skype Call button on top of the home page and to align it with flags (EN and RU) of the language switcher. Now after I put your code into custom.css, it corrected the issue with the text in the article, but Skype Call button is now too low and I want it back on the same level as two language change flags.

Comment: I'll take a look at that tomorrow. Will probably be a simple CSS tweak